# Entity Framework multiple simple request causing StackOverflowExceptions

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am debugging weird issue that occurred in my company software.

Multiple request ( > 10 000 ) are causing `StackOverflow exception` or so high memory usage that other part of software are crashing.

When I was testing our code I found that even very simple requests like `Test` method is causing this huge memory gain:

```
public void Test()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        using (var db = new FruitsDBEntity())
        {
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

            var any = db.Fruits.AsNoTracking().Any();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not using any .Include() with navigation properties but I wonder if navigation properties configuration could cause that issue.

That's my model of `FruitsDBEntity` :

```
public partial class Fruit
{
    [Key]
    public long FruitId { get; set; }

    public long TreeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TreeId")]
    public Tree Tree { get; set; } //Navigation property

    public List<FruitMetaData> FruitMetaData { get; set; }
}

public partial class FruitMetaData
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long FruitId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string MetaType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Fruit Fruit { get; set; } // Navigation property 
}

public partial class Tree
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public long TreeId { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string TreeName { get; set; }

    public List<Fruit>   TreeFruits { get; set; }
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    Database.SetInitializer<FruitsDBEntity>(null);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Tree>()
            .HasMany(e => e.TreeFruits)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Tree)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Fruit>()
                .HasMany(e => e.FruitMetaData)
                .WithRequired(e => e.Fruit)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

}
```

I will appreciate any help.

**[EDIT]**
**My configuration:**
**.NET version:** 4.5 but I've tested that also on 4.5.2 with the same result
**Entity Framework version:** 6.1.3
**SQL Server version:** Tested on SQL Server 2016 Express and SQL Server 2016 Developer. Both on the same machine.
**Tested on:** 
a) 2C/4T + 8GB RAM
b) 4C/8T + 16GB RAM
Both Windows 10

Full Exception message:

`System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll`

Comment: These aren't multiple simple requests. You are opening **1M** connections and load *everything* in memory in a tight loop, before the garbage collector has a chance to clean things up. This is a resource leak caused by the code itself, not an issue with EF

Comment: *Why* are you trying this? Are you trying to solve some other problem? Benchmark a misbehaving query? Don't know how to load multiple objects with a single statement? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I doubt it opens 1M connections. Because of connection pool, connections can be reuses. And because it is sequential synchronous loop - it should actually open just 1 connection. Also, Any does not load anything to memory.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I am creating and disposing single connection in single iteration. 
GarbageCollector is not collecting those objects from memory even if I will force him. My problem is high memory usage which is causing crash of application. That's basically the issue I am fighting with.

Comment: @Wiktor if you want to investigate an unrealistic edge case, post the full exception.

Comment: So are you getting StackOverflow exception or OutOfMemory exception? Those are quite different.

Comment: @Evk you are right, although this scenario is unrealistic, it *does* create garbage even if it's just the booleans and contexts (1M of them). Without the full exception one can't even begin to search for an answer. I also suspect the specific runtime version will play a role

Comment: @Wiktor you are allocating a lot of objects in a tight loop, which doesn't allow the garbage collector to clean up *or* defragment memory. OOM exceptions can be thrown if the runtime can't find a  block of free memory large enough to satisfy a request.

Comment: @Evk: What I am truly getting is SqlException "A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)".

Comment: @Wiktor the runtime version also matters. Later versions allow background garbage collection. Without it, your code would prevent the GC from running until the loop ended

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I've got the latest version of Entity Framework.

Comment: @Wiktor Please post the **actual exception**. You have mentioned StackOverflow, Out Of Memory and now a *connection* error. Are you trying to hit a local SQL Express instance?

Comment: @Wiktor I said *runtime*. Please, either edit this question and provide full information or post a new one. You change the type of error and exception with each message. If you run everything on a single weak machine with SQL Express (which uses only 1 core) you may not be allowing *anything* to run, resulting in dropped connections and random exceptions.

Comment: If its something related to GC and 1M booleans and contexts, how about declaring those variables outside the for loop? `bool any; FruitsDBEntity db;` - will this make any difference? What exact error message are you getting?

Comment: @Developer to the SQL exception? No. To OOM? Why? The variable is the *alias* not the object. Actually, it would make things worse - the last value would survive the loop. Putting the context outside the loop would make a lot of difference though *and* change the code significantly - single context, single connection, no garbage contexts. Just 1M queries

Comment: @Developer you are right about the context, it's the most complex object in this case. We are missing a LOT of information here

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The exception thrown in my real app is thrown in random places because it is multi thread app. And exceptions name can be different. But every exception is always thrown when memory usage is going up to 1.7 GB. That's why I did test of that loop and checked why it is even happening. The cause of the exception in this thread is actually causing also other exceptions in my app.

Comment: But then that single context is gonna be real real heavy and that's gonna slog.. *Update* - missed the `AsNoTracking()` - context might not be that heavy due to this. Again as you said, we dont have info about how complex the context is

Comment: @Wiktor all EF applications, especially web applications are multi-threaded. Instead of testing with an unrealistic loop, profile your actual code. Post a question about *the actual problem*. I suspect you'll find some memory leaks you didn't expect

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: That is my actual problem. I've got milions of lines which I need to check if exists in Table. If they are not exists then I have to Insert them. I cannot do that at once with BulkInsert. I need to go through all of them. This code is actually what I have found after my investigation. .NET version is 4.5. I am also using machine with 4C/8T and 16GB of RAM.

Comment: @Wiktor You can't *not* do this with Bulk Insert or SqlBulkCopy. You are trying to use tweezers (the ORM) to carry truckloads of rocks. Use SqlBulkCopy to insert the data into a staging table then either use MERGE or `UPSERT/INSERT` to update the target table. ORMs aren't meant for ETL or reporting. The difference in speed can be O(N), or 1M times for 1M rows

Comment: @Wiktor I need to import several thousand rows into a datamart with a few dozen million rows. Anything that can't be read with SSIS, gets parsed, the objects converted to datatables with MoreLINQ's ToDataTable and imported with SqlBulkCopy. The ORM is only used for the web UI

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos _"You are opening 1M connections and load everything in memory in a tight loop, before the garbage collector has a chance to clean things up"_ - utter nonsense. 1) GC can pre-empt your app 2) he is using a `using` block.  3) [here is the evidence](http://imgur.com/K39vhko) from my machine showing **GC is running**

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos _"you are allocating a lot of objects in a tight loop, which doesn't allow the garbage collector to clean up or defragment memory"_ - incorrect.  Ask any XNA game developer

Comment: @MickyD check the rest of the comments before making such bold statements, especially when you aren't certain that the server GC is used. The OP is trying to upsert 1M rows and thought that EF was at fault. So he tried 1M checks in a tight loop

Comment: @MickyD actually, you should ensure that the runtime uses the background GC before talking in absolutes. Also consider what 1M queries would do to a local database.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can back up my "bold" claims with a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/K39vhko)?  Where's yours?  Why not show that instead of posting bossy comments to everyone

Comment: @MickyD 3 comments before your first comment. The OP is trying to upsert 1M rows. Even if the test run succesfuly, 1M upserts would still cause a huge waste of memory. The solution is to use SqlBulkCopy to a staging table and upsert/merge

Comment: @MickyD if you can't repro, by all means post that comment, or even vote to close as `can't repro`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You're right I can't reproduce your claims

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: But I am not trying in that case to upsert anything and still I am receiving huge memory gain.
GC is not collecting anything. That's what I see.  [screen](http://imgur.com/a/KFfrq) . My SqlServer version is Sql Server 2016 Developer edition which can use unlimited number of cores.

Comment: @Wiktor I suspect that if you run your code without debugging you'll see a huge difference. The debugger keeps track of everything even when running on Release mode and keeps disposed object for a lot longer.

Comment: @Wiktor Can you collate any comments about your setup and add to your post.  I just used your code on my own database **without any problem**.  **GC correctly runs as expected** (in and out of debugger) irrespective of the loop and memory use stayed **steady 20MB**.  The only thing that a background GC will do is not lock up the main thread.  The bizare notion that someone raised that .NET is too dumb to perform GC during a loop is just ridiculous.  I'm sure every single XNA app out there on Windows; Windows Phone and the Xbox would fail

Comment: @Wiktor you've raised several different questions in the comments, all of which have been discussed before. The background GC, upserts, the debugger's effects on GC and memory.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I've tried that already. It's not helping. This method is causing to use 200 MB of memory after just 20 000 iterations. It's not normal!

Comment: @MickyD XNA isn't the runtime. Neither is .NET dumb - background GC was [added in 4.5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps/).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Exactly my point.

Comment: @Wiktor 200MB down from 1.7GB? Anyway, you'll never be able to get acceptable performance from individual SQL statements. Acceptable performance is a few seconds or less for upserting a couple-hundred rows into a 1M table. Merging large tables is a different matter. It would still run orders of magnitude faster that row-by-row but would lock other users for quite some time

Comment: @Wiktor if you do this to detect changes, you could use SQL Server's Change Tracking on the source table to pull only the modified rows. This takes a bit more storage on the source but it's essentially transparent and supported on all versions. How many source rows do you have to merge and how many differences are there each time?

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks for the edit

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I found that issue because [previously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024529/debuging-memory-leak-vs2015-massive-native-heap?noredirect=1#comment71230122_42024529) I was trying to find massive native heap memory usage. It was filled with hundreds of thousands of objects with size of  8192 bytes. Now I know it is caused by this loop. GC doesn't want to collect those data. Even if I force him to Collect every 1000 iterations. I've tried on .NET 4.6.2 and EF 6.0.0, 6.1.3. If you can't reproduce that, maybe there is something wrong with my configuration in the end.

Comment: @MickyD : Could you please confirm that even when you are doing 20 000 iterations, the memory usage is still on ~20MB? I've created a new database, new Entity Model, and still have that issue.

Comment: @Wiktor Yes.  Memory remains steady.  [This picture clearly shows GC is running throughout.  Note memory snapshots too](http://imgur.com/a/g5v6s)

Comment: @Wiktor [...and here is the whole diagnostic session](http://imgur.com/a/g5v6s)

Comment: @MickyD Thank you! I can see in Visual Studio Profiler and ANTS Memory Profiler that all of that space in my memory is taken by Unmanaged Memory.